# Creating a paper consisting of included subfiles (package standalone) all with a ToC

Tags: subfiles

So I have a paper which consists out of a main body and several included subfiles who must be able to compile standalone.
Therefore, I am using the package standalone and created the main.tex file as follows, with the two other main files being the included, possible to be standalone, files:

```
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{niflheim_tutorial/main_niflheim_tutorial.tex}
\input{yggdrasil/main_yggdrasil.tex}

\end{document}
```

This works well but produces a table of contents (ToC) in the main file and empty ToCs in the other files.

Screenshots from the main ToC:

[image]

Screenshot from the ToC of main_niflheim_tutorial:

[image]

Ideally, the main ToC would first list something like [Niflheim_Tutorial] then give the ToC of that file.
The ToC in the other files should be non empty as well.

Any idea on how to do this?